# TWOSQRS SPOJ using Python 2.7.9 gives a run-time error(NZEC)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I was trying to solve the TWOSQRS problem at SPOJ using Python 2.7.9 as my coding language and designed a program to do so. As the code runs perfectly without raising any exceptions on my system with given test case inputs. It would be helpful if someone could provide me more test cases or find the bug in my code.

Link to problem: http://www.spoj.com/problems/TWOSQRS/

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''To solve the problem 2 primary condition that should be met are:
    1. No should not be of the form 4k+3 as for sum of square of two nos will always be of form 4k or 4k+1
    2. All the prime factors of form 4k+3 should have even power from the Fermat thorem.
   Steps involved in solving the problem are:
    1. Sieve a list of prime nos. upto 1000001 as in problem. 
    2. Check if all the prime factors has even powers.
    3. Check if the no is not of form 4k+3'''

import numpy

def sieve(n):
    """ An implementation that sieves separately 
    for primes of the form 6i−1 and 6i+1, due to Robert William Hanks"""

    prime = numpy.ones(n//3 + (n%6==2), dtype=numpy.bool)
    for i in range(3, int(n**.5) + 1, 3):
        if prime[i // 3]:
            p = (i + 1) | 1
            prime[       p*p//3     ::2*p] = False
            prime[p*(p-2*(i&1)+4)//3::2*p] = False
    result = (3 * prime.nonzero()[0] + 1) | 1
    result[0] = 3
    return numpy.r_[2,result]

primes=sieve(10**6+1)            #List of all the prime upto 10**6

def main():
    noOfCase=input()
    for i in range(noOfCase):
        N=input()
        is_multiple= True
        i = 0
        while(primes[i]*primes[i] <= N):
       count = 0;
       while (N % primes[i] == 0):
           count+=1;
           N/= primes[i];
           if (primes[i]%4 == 3 and count%2 == 1):
               is_multiple = False;
               break;
           i+=1

    if (N%4 == 3):
       is_multiple = False
    if(is_multiple):
       print "Yes"
    else:
       print "No"


main()
```

Comment: SPOJ will not have numpy

Comment: @thefourtheye Yes you are correct, thanks for notifying me about that.

Comment: But [SPOJ _does_ have NumPy](http://www.spoj.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=22493&sid=75e77618dd09c8c79b74fea762af8bea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is almost certainly that you're using NumPy, but selecting a Python cluster/version that doesn't support it.

As [PYTHON: What you should know](http://www.spoj.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=22493&sid=75e77618dd09c8c79b74fea762af8bea) explains, the Pyramid cluster does not have NumPy for any Python versions, the Cube cluster has it for all CPython versions but no PyPy versions.

Comment: So how do we choose the Cube cluster ??

Comment: @AkashSingh: There used to be a choice. When I try to submit a solution right now, it just tells me "Your submission will be judged on the Cube Cluster (Intel Pentium G860 3GHz)". It may be that you always get it now?

Comment: Thanks @abarnert I just found out about it and also that it was judging on the Cube cluster for the code above but still getting an error.